# How to get the correct items based on number of items, items per page and page number?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
let array = [
  { name: 'name1', price: '555' },
  { name: 'nam2', price: '666' }
]
```

I'm wondering how to get the correct item based on the number of items, items per page and page number? For example, if I have `itemsPerPage = 1` and `pageNumber = 0`, I'd need to return the first object only. If I had `itemsPerPage = 1` and `pageNumber = 1`, I'd need to return the second object and if I had `itemsPerPage = 2` and `pageNumber = 0`, I'd need to return both objects.

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to use the `totalItems`, `itemsPerPage` and `pageNumber` to determine which object am I meant to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code, I also used the array you provided and possible use cases

Everything that needs to be explained was written as a comment in the code

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'name1',
    price: '555'
  },
  {
    name: 'nam2',
    price: '666'
  }
];

function returnRelevantAmount(amountPerPage, pageNumber) {
  if (!amountPerPage) return []; // If amountPerPage is 0
  const start = (pageNumber * amountPerPage); // how many to offset the slice by
  const end = start + amountPerPage; // offset + amountRequired
  
  return array.slice(start, end);
}

console.log(returnRelevantAmount(1, 0));
console.log(returnRelevantAmount(2, 0));
console.log(returnRelevantAmount(1, 1));
```

A possible one liner would be

```
const returnRelevantAmount = (amountPerPage, pageNumber) => (!amountPerPage) ? [] : array.slice((pageNumber * amountPerPage), ((pageNumber * amountPerPage) + amountPerPage));
```